# split array value in table by php

Tags: php

I hava a string and its

```
$value ='xyz:101,xyz:102,xyz:103,xyz:104,xyz:105,ABC:201,xyz:202,xyz:203,xyz:204,xyz:205';
```

And I want to show this value in a table like

```html
<table width='50%' border='1' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='10'>
  <tr>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Code</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>XYZ</td>
    <td>101</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>XYZ</td>
    <td>102</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>XYZ</td>
    <td>103</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>XYZ</td>
    <td>104</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>XYZ</td>
    <td>105</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>201</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>202</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>203</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>204</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>205</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

can anybody help me for this

Comment: xyz:101 is  key:value pair...? if is the value then it is array or simple string?

Comment: it is a value pair

Comment: array or string?

Comment: How far have you come? Any code to share?

Comment: So what have you tried? Please note that this is a place offering help if you have issues with your own code. We are not here to do your work for you, for that please hire a (payed) programmer. We expect you to start yourself, implement what you need and ask if you run into a problem you cannot solve yourself.

Comment: it is a array value

Comment: `xyz:101` is `key:value` or `value` only?

Comment: xyz is key and 101 is value

Comment: @DeshuYadav You should accept the answer you find correct. You can take the tour and find out how to accept answers https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 3):

Explode the values on comma and colon and you get an array with the values. Then output them accordingly.

```
$value='xyz:101,xyz:102,xyz:103,xyz:104,xyz:105,ABC:201,xyz:202,xyz:203,xyz:204,xyz:205';

$arr = explode(",", $value);

Foreach($arr as $pair){
    $parts =explode(":", $pair);
    Echo "<tr>\n<td>";
    Echo $parts[0];
    Echo "</td>\n<td>";
    Echo $parts[1];
    Echo "</td>\n</tr>";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/TbtbX

Comment: @simhumileco sure... Anything else I can help you with? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Please check below mentioned solution. This will help you.

```
$str = 'xyz:101,xyz:102,xyz:103,xyz:104,xyz:105,ABC:201,xyz:202,xyz:203,xyz:204,xyz:205';
$array = explode(',', $str);
$temp = array();
foreach ($array as $i => $j):
    $temp[$i] = explode(':', $j);
endforeach;
?>
<table width='50%' border='1' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='10'>
    <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Code</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($temp as $value): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $value[0] ?></td>
            <td><?= $value[1] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Let me know if it not works.

Comment: $val is key value pair as @Deshu Yadav mention in comment

Comment: Please check in question comments.

Answer (score 1):

Even if I don't like spoonfeeding, there you go:

```
<?php  
$value='xyz:101,xyz:102,xyz:103,xyz:104,xyz:105,ABC:201,xyz:202,xyz:203,xyz:204,xyz:205';

$array = explode(",", $value);
?>

<table width='50%' border='1' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='10'>
    <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Code</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($array as $value) :
    $exploded = explode(":", $value);
    $key = $exploded[0];
    $value = $exploded[1];
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: $val is key value pair as @Deshu Yadav mention in comment

Answer (score 0):

IF it is key value pair the use foreach :

```
foreach ($value as $key => $v) {
  echo "<tr>";      
  echo "<td>".$key."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$v."</td>"; 
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `value=''` is a part of your string; get quotations content by this code

```
$string = "value='xyz:101,xyz:102,xyz:103,xyz:104,xyz:105,ABC:201,xyz:202,xyz:203,xyz:204,xyz:205'";
$matches = array();
preg_match( '/value=\'([^\']*)\'/i', $string, $matches ) ;
$content = $matches[0];
```

and use this code to generate table :

```
echo "<table width='50%' border='1' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='10'>";
$array = explode(',', $content);
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $data = explode(':', $item);
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "  <th>$data[0]</th>";
    echo "  <th>$data[1]</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Don't use regex to split a simple string.

Comment: @Andreas i'm explained 'If value='' is a part of string' use regex , it's not for split

Comment: Yes it is! Use substr() if you know the first seven chars are not supposed to be there and the last one use substr. That is what the function is there for. Regex however is not meant to split simple strings. You are using far more time and memory on a simple task that substr and explode can do. Very poor answer in my opinion.

Comment: Also have you tried the code? Your content is the same as the string.

Answer (score 0):

Use `explode()` and `foreach`:

```
<?php

$value = 'xyz:101,xyz:102,xyz:103,xyz:104,xyz:105,ABC:201,xyz:202,xyz:203,xyz:204,xyz:205';

$rows = explode(',', $value);

?>
<table width='50%' border='1' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='10'>
    <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Code</th>
    </tr>
<?php

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $values = explode(':', $row);

?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $values[0]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $values[1]; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php

}

?>
</table>
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

For an example, see:

- https://3v4l.org/tJcrc